# PHP: Namespaced function arguments

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I just noticed in Laravel a usage of functions that have their arguments namespaced:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

class PurchasePodcast implements SelfHandling
{

    protected $mailer;

    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }
```

I couldn't find anywhere informations about what these are or what they do. Are they supposed to be instances of objects in that particular namespace? If so, where do I instantiate them?

Comment: They are not namespaced, they are typehinted.

Comment: IF we're talking about the constructor argument, it's type-hinted as having to be and instance of class `Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations. So, typehinting only happens in the constructor function, and in the other functions it's just namespacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for the dependency-injector. In short: You tell Laravel what you need and Laravel passes it to you.

In PHP you can type-hint parameters to all functions, not only the constructor. In your case, the parameter to your constructor is typehinted as `Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer`, this means, you are only allowed to pass a `Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer` (or a subclass) for this parameter. Laravels Dependency-Injector will now use this information, which it gets through reflection, to give you what you want, a `Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer`. You can typehint a wide range of things, even your own classes. You could even type-hint a parameter for your controller-function with `App\Jobs\PurchasePodcast` and Laravel will happily create and pass one to you.

Comment: Or if it implements an interface an interface of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

Arguments that are objects from namespace must be namespaced so PHP will know what Object type to use.
In your case you don't have namespaced arguments to __construct, just Mailer which refers to Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer. You can also define other name if you wish like:
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer as myMailer;